# Mapped Errors after updating model from sql server to edmx

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, mapping, edmx

At first i have some database tables which are not linked in the EDMX and SQL server , so i decided to link them up and update them from SQL server to EDMX in Visual Studio and it shows 3 errors that i don't understand . I am using Entity Framework too .

This is how my SQL server db looks like :
[image]

However when i update it to EDMX in visual studio , it doesn't show the way it is .

EDMX visual studio ( Ignore the 2 diagram on the right) :

[image]

And errors has it shown :

[image]

If the screenshot is too small :
here is the error ( 3 errors when building edmx ):

> Error 3   Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   665, 698:**Foreign key constraint 'FK_threeHints_ActivityTask' from
>   table threeHints (ActivityID, TaskID) to table ActivityTask
>   (activityID, taskID)**:: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be
>   mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign
>   key association on the conceptual side.
>
> Error 2   Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   637, 698:**Foreign key constraint 'FK_questions_ActivityTask' from table
>   questions (ActivityID, TaskID) to table ActivityTask (activityID,
>   taskID):: Insufficient mapping**: Foreign key must be mapped to some
>   AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key
>   association on the conceptual side.
>
> Error 1   Error 3015: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines
>   627, 698:**Foreign key constraint 'FK_questionhint_ActivityTask' from
>   table questionhint (ActivityID, TaskID) to table ActivityTask
>   (activityID, taskID)**:: Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be
>   mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign
>   key association on the conceptual side.

Why doesn't the SQL server db reflects on what it looks like at edmx?

Comment: did you try to map it in manually?

Comment: nope , as i am new to this , how do i do it manually?